# How to boot SONY VAIO notebook from USB stick?

Tags: sony-vaio

I have a [VAIO notebook](http://www.sony.ru/product/vaio-serii-e/sve1512l1r) and I want to boot it from USB flash. How could that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was found that there is a ASSIST button in the keyboard which turns this notebook on and shows system menu.